# Picking two different random numbers fast

Tags: algorithm, performance, random, language-agnostic, pseudocode

Sometimes one requires random numbers with the condition that they are unique.

The classic algorithm is to keep looping until you hit the different numbers by chance, some pseudo code:

```
 minval = 0 ;
 maxval = 4 ; // random max will be one less than maxval

 val1 = random( minval , maxval ) ;
 val2 = random( minval , maxval ) ;

 while( val1 == val2 ) {

  val2 = random( minval , maxval ) ;

 }
```

I have a time critical and memory limited program and was wondering if there are any algorithms that avoid the continuous loop brute force method without using extra memory like a look up table.

Probably a simple solution but it's a late and tired evening here.

Any tips?

Comment: For a small ranges, random shuffle the range and pick two first entries. The real answer depends on many constraints, including the desired distribution.

Comment: There are 4 x 4 or 16 possibilities for crossing val1 and val2. Do want the pairs (like {0, 3}, {2, 3}) to be randomly distributed (excluding {i, i} of course)? This would exclude just bumping val2 by 1 if it were the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can exclude the already found number like this:

```
 minval = 0 ;
 maxval = 4 ; // random max will be one less than maxval

 val1 = random( minval , maxval ) ;
 val2 = random( minval , maxval - 1 ) ;

 if(val2 >= val1) val2++;
```

The second time, specify an interval of one less than the first one, and shift the part above the already found number up by one.

Comment: Do you mean "==" in the if or am I confused?

Comment: No, `>=` is correct because it shifts the whole range above the found number, else the chance for getting `val1 + 1` would be twice as big as for other numbers, and you could not get `maxval - 1` the second time.